# Splitting field of $f(x)=x^4+3$ in $\mathbb{Q}[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory

I am trying to find the splitting field of $f(x)=x^4+3$ over $\mathbb Q$.

It is irreducible, and the roots are 
$$\sqrt[4]{3}(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}),\sqrt[4]{3}(\frac{-\sqrt{2}}{2}\pm\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$$

I claimed the splitting field is $E=\mathbb Q(\sqrt[4]{3},\sqrt{2},i)$

Now, I supposed $K$ is any other splitting field,  after some calculation I proved $\sqrt 3,\sqrt{2}\sqrt[4]{3},i $ in $K$

How to show $\sqrt[4]{3}$ or $\sqrt {2}$ in $K$.

Comment: I think you listed four real roots but all four roots of that polynomial must have $\text{im}(z)\not=0$.

Comment: You seem to be thinking of $x^4-3$, not $x^4+3$.

Comment: Let $\zeta=\frac{\sqrt{2}}2+\frac{\sqrt{2}}2i$.  Then $\zeta, \zeta^3, \zeta^5, \zeta^7$ are the four 4th roots of $-1$.  Let $z=\sqrt[4]{3}$.  Then $z\zeta$, $z\zeta^3$, $z\zeta^5$, $z\zeta^7$ are the four roots of $f$.  Thus $\frac{z\zeta^3}{z\zeta}=\zeta^2=i$ is in the splitting field.    But I don't think $\sqrt[4]{3}$ is in there.

Comment: sorry , I forgot to put $i $ in second parts of $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: So, Gregory, what is the splitting field? is it $\mathbb Q (\sqrt {2}\sqrt[4]{3},i)$? ( I'm just thinking about it )